# `func(a, _ int, z float32) bool` declaration in go spec language

Tags: go, specifications

In the specification of the go language, at func specification there is an example I don't understand: `func(a, _ int, z float32) bool` is this syntax possible ? You can find it there: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_types

I've tried a snippet of code that does not works based on this example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func f(a, _ int, z float32) bool {
    if a == _ && z == 17.3 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f(10, 10, 17.3))
}
```

I get a compiler error: `cannot use _ as value` which is normal.

So does somebody knows why they put this weird syntax as an example of function's type ?

Comment: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Blank_identifier

Comment: the blank identifier isn't a value: https://go.dev/play/p/nwYR9BFvzsH

Answer (score -1):

While editing my post I found the answer. The specific example I do not understand is for declaring a func type not to declare a function itself.

So the following snippet works:

```golang
type MyFunc func(a, _ int) bool

func main() {
    var f1 MyFunc
    f1 = func(a, b int) bool {
        return a == b
    }
    fmt.Println(f1(10, 10))
}
```